# How to make inline images responsive in smaller screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm looping through some images in my rails app"

```
<% @attachments.each do |attachment| %>
  <div class="img-thumbnail" style="display:inline-block; margin:auto; text-align: center; padding-top: 15px; width: 120px;">
    <%=image_tag attachment.images_url(:thumb).to_s %>
      <div class="desc">
        <%= link_to "Remove", remove_image_path(attachment), data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this image?" }, :method => :delete, :style => "text-decoration: none !important" %>
      </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The images appear inline and they start from the left side which is exactly what I wanted. Now I'm wondering if there is a way I can make the image take up the 100% width only when the screen is smaller?

I created a dummy snippet for help.

```css
.form-border {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;

}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      <div class="container form-border">
        <div class="img-thumbnail" style="display:inline-block; margin:auto; text-align: center; padding-top: 15px; width: 120px;">
          <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
          <div class="desc">Remove</div>
          <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
          <div class="desc">Remove</div
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update A**

I followed @agustin answer by doing the doing:

```
<div class="img-thumbnail" style="display:inline-block; margin:auto; text-align: center; padding-top: 15px; width: 120px;">
  <div class="img-fluid">
    <%=image_tag attachment.images_url(:thumb).to_s %>
 </div>
</div
```

or

```
<div class="img-thumbnail" style="display:inline-block; margin:auto; text-align: center; padding-top: 15px; max-width: 100%;;">
  <div class="img-fluid">
    <%=image_tag attachment.images_url(:thumb).to_s %>
  </div>
 </div
```

but I still get the same result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have errors in your layout.

1. Remember that you shouldn't create another `.container` element inside a `col` or `row` element. The correct way is `.container` > `.row`> `.col`, and if you want columns inside a column, then you have to create another `.row` with `.col`s inside, but not another container.
2. The `img-fluid` class has to be applied to the `img` element. You will probably want to define the width of the image though.

Check the following snippet. I created two columns with the class `col-md-6`, which means that, on medium screens (≥768px), those columns will take 50% of the width of the row each. As I didn't define any class with `col-sm` or `col-xs`, those columns will take 100% of the width of the row on small screens.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="img-thumbnail">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300/" class="img-fluid" alt="Italian Trulli">
            <div class="desc">Remove</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="img-thumbnail">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300/" class="img-fluid" alt="Italian Trulli">
            <div class="desc">Remove</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @agustin, I tried both and for some reason none worked for me... I updated my question with some info, please check it out if you can.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about <img> elements. What you need to do there is to use media queries to set the width of the column to 100% when the width of the window is smaller than X number of pixels.

Comment: I would need more HTML and CSS to help you more. Can you update your answer with a snippet showing a result similar to your screenshot?

Comment: I just updated the snippet.. its suppose to render the images inline but for some reason its not in the snippet, on my end they are inline. Take a look and let me know what you can do!